# How to add dfs with different number of column axis levels, but sharing same axis names?

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe, multi-level

I have two multi-level column dataframes:

```
data = {
    'A': {
        'X': {'Value1': 2, 'Value2': 1},
        'Y': {'Value1': 2, 'Value2': 3}
    },
    'B': {
        'X': {'Value1': 10, 'Value2': 11},
        'Y': {'Value1': 10, 'Value2': 11}
    }
}

df = pd.DataFrame(data)
```

Which looks like this...

```
Group          A                           B                                   
Subgroup        X            Y             X             Y                        
Metric         Value1 Value2 Value1 Value2 Value1 Value2 Value1 Value2
2023-01-01        2     1     2     3     10     11     10     11
2023-01-02        2     1     2     3     10     11     10     11
2023-01-03        2     1     2     3     10     11     10     11
2023-01-04        2     1     2     3     10     11     10     11
2023-01-05        2     1     2     3     10     11     10     11
```

```
df2:

data = {
    'A': {'Value1': [3, 3, 1, 3, 3], 'Value2': [5, 2, 2, 2, 2]},
    'B': {'Value1': [3, 4, 7, 3, 3], 'Value2': [2, 2, 7, 2, 2]}
}

df_2 = pd.DataFrame(data, index=pd.to_datetime(['2023-01-01', 
'2023-01-02', '2023-01-03', '2023-01-04', '2023-01-05']))

# Convert to constructor
df2 = df_2.unstack().unstack()
```

Which looks like this...

```
Group          A             B                                                 
Metric         Value1 Value2 Value1 Value2 
2023-01-01        3      5     3     2    
2023-01-02        3      2     4     2      
2023-01-03        1      2     7     7    
2023-01-04        3      2     3     2       
2023-01-05        3      2     3     2
```

and would like to add df2 to df1, but for each combination of Group and Metric, add across each Subgroup that match to look like this...

```
Group          A                           B                                   
Subgroup        X            Y             X             Y                        
Metric         Value1 Value2 Value1 Value2 Value1 Value2 Value1 Value2
2023-01-01        5     6     5     5     13     13     13     13
2023-01-02        5     3     6     5     14     15     14     13
2023-01-03        3     3     9     10    17     18     17     18
2023-01-04        5     3     5     5     13     14     13     13
2023-01-05        5     3     5     5     13     14     13     13
```

Any help would be appreciated.

Some ideas like merging but I think i lose the middle subgroup level above but could have been doing it incorrectly.

Comment: Please provide your dataframes as constructors for reproducibility

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think the easiest might be to [`droplevel`](https://pandas.pydata.org/docs/reference/api/pandas.DataFrame.droplevel.html) on df1, then [`add`](https://pandas.pydata.org/docs/reference/api/pandas.DataFrame.add.html), finally recreate the DataFrame:

```
pd.DataFrame(df1.droplevel('Subgroup', axis=1).add(df2).to_numpy(),
             index=df1.index, columns=df1.columns)
```

Alternatively, reindex df2 and convert to numpy:

```
df1 += df2.reindex_like(df1.droplevel('Subgroup', axis=1)).to_numpy()
```

Output:

```
Group           A                           B                     
Subgroup        X             Y             X             Y       
Metric     Value1 Value2 Value1 Value2 Value1 Value2 Value1 Value2
2023-01-01      5      5      6      8     13     13     13     13
2023-01-02      5      5      3      5     14     14     13     13
2023-01-03      3      3      3      5     17     17     18     18
2023-01-04      5      5      3      5     13     13     13     13
2023-01-05      5      5      3      5     13     13     13     13
```

Comment: The second solution worked perfectly, I tried the first, but ended with this error: AssertionError: Gaps in blk ref_locs

Comment: Also ill mention, this is a cool and unique approach, again appreciate the response.